# 2006 IMO Shortlist Questions A1 proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, contest-math

I have nearly completed the proof for A1 on this pdf: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2006SL.pdf. However, I just need final clarification on the series given at the end with the following equation:

[image]

My question basically is why are the 2 alternate values the following values: [image]

Comment: Have you tried substituting $i_0,i_{0}+2, \dots$ for $i$ in this equation?  Same question for $i_0+1,i_0+3,\dots$.

Comment: My question is based on the fact that ai converges to 2 numbers between -1 and 0 thus stating that from some point the difference between the values in the series should be less than 1 however using the alternate values that they gave the difference should be over 1.

Comment: You should put your question in the body, not the comments.  Also, please try to clarify it.  I don't understand what you are asking.  First you seem to say you don't know how they get the answer, and now you seem to say you think it is wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz My question is summarised in the last sentence of the body. If you are wondering how to answer it then I would say in terms of pointing out where in the proof it suggests that those 2 values are the alternate values.